# Javascript search box and character counter

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple HTML web page that returns words upon keyup. I want the lowest character value from a list of strings.

The following code has been taken from [link](https://codepen.io/rachelhawa/pen/vYBjQMY):

```
function mySearchFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, item, i, txtValue;
  // User Input
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  // Filter, makes search not case sensitive
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  // Grabs the parent element by id
  ul = document.getElementById("stateList");
  // Individual item on list
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

  // Treats lists items like an array, where each item can be accessed through      it's index
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    item = li[i];
   // Iterate over each list item to see if the value of the input, ignoring         case, matches the inner text or inner html of the item.
    txtValue = item.textContent || item.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    // Displays list items that are a match, and nothing if no match
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like is another search box that works synchronously with the above function, or any implementation fo a search function, which takes a number as input, passes it to the search function, so in the end, it all returns the original search function but only with the number of characters specified from the other function.

It doesn't have to be 2 different search boxes, and also there are around 2,100 strings to be searched.

For example:

list of words in the list: apple, app, appreciation
input: ap, 6
output: apple, appreciation

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "but only with the number of characters specified "

Comment: @Gopikrishna I mean that from the list of strings, I would like the output to be what https://codepen.io/rachelhawa/pen/vYBjQMY already does, but another input box where for example the input was "mi" and "8", it wouldn't show Missouri, but would show "Mississippi".

Comment: Can tell what exactly the number values does to the search. Because I can't get your question , what's the significance of 8,6....etc number . "mi" and "8" its clear that you want strings with "mi" but unclear what 8 does.

Comment: @Gopikrishna sorry for the confusion. 8 signifies the least number of characters that the search result should show.

Answer (score 2):

If you send n=0 , then it will work as your current search box , else as your second search box.

```
function mySearchFunction(n) {
      // Declare variables
      var input, filter, ul, li, item, i, txtValue;
      // User Input
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      // Filter, makes search not case sensitive
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      // Grabs the parent element by id
      ul = document.getElementById("stateList");
      // Individual item on list
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    
      // Treats lists items like an array, where each item can be accessed through      it's index
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        item = li[i];
       // Iterate over each list item to see if the value of the input, ignoring         case, matches the inner text or inner html of the item.
        txtValue = item.textContent || item.innerText;
        if (txtValue.length > n && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        // Displays list items that are a match, and nothing if no match
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the respone! Can you give me some example inputs since when I try entering anything, nothing returns.

Comment: Use this input tag instead yours , you will get an idea how it works.<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearchFunction(0)" placeholder="Search">

Comment: Could you send a working example, maybe a jsfiddle? When I run this, I have to manually change the amount of characters needed in the javascript. Could you make that value change from another textbox?

Comment: Please have a look into this , https://jsfiddle.net/zw2s869j/14/

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there a way to make the number input synchronized with the word input which already syncs with the output, because you have to change the word input currently for the number input to take effect. So in other words, is there a way to make the number input directly affect the output? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clearly explain what you are expecting . Based on what n should be defined .

Comment: search box should make output what search box is searching for ofcourse, and then the next box should make the output be the only n characters at least. Currently, you have to change the search term for the n character search to work, and I want it to work without you having to change the search term.